# Запросы к  бд

Tags: android

Хочу уточнить, если я делаю любой запрос с БД, где параметром query есть поля, которые мне надо вывести, то мне нужно указывать перечень всех полей таблицы? или можно скормить ему null?

**UPD.**  или достаточно параметром передать * (звездочку)?

Comment: покажите, как делаете запрос.

Comment: Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE, new String[] {"*"}, null....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если почитать [документацию](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)), то там сказано, что можно передавать null вторым параметром, тогда будут все поля.